# BLE - didDiscoverServices is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've seen a few questions of this nature, but none of them seems to resolve my situation. I'm trying to connect to a BLE device. All goes along well until I get to the callback

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
```

It seems that this is never called. Here is what I have:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    self.connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.connected);

    [peripheral setDelegate:self];

    if (peripheral.services) {
        [self peripheral:peripheral didDiscoverServices:nil]; //already discovered services, DO NOT re-discover. Just pass along the peripheral.
    } else {
        [peripheral discoverServices:nil]; //yet to discover, normal path. Discover your services needed
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"here");

    for(CBService* svc in peripheral.services)
    {
        if(svc.characteristics)
            [self peripheral:peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:svc error:nil]; //already discovered characteristic before, DO NOT do it again
        else
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil
                                     forService:svc]; //need to discover characteristics

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Discovered service: %@", svc.UUID];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
        [self appendTextToDeviceInfo:string];
    }

}
```

I can see the log output:

> Connected: YES

but that is it. Nothing in the didDiscoverServices callback ever seems to be invoked. I've deleted and re-installed the app, and also restarted the device.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

**EDIT**
Here is the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import CoreBluetooth;
@import QuartzCore;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *myPeripheral;

@end
```

**EDIT #2**

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0) {

        NSLog(@"Found the device: %@", localName);

        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral]; //IMPORTANT, to clear off any pending connections
        [_centralManager stopScan];
        _myPeripheral = peripheral;
        _myPeripheral.delegate = self;
        [_centralManager connectPeripheral:_myPeripheral options:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you saved a reference to your connected peripheral in a `strong` property?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll add the .h file to the post.

Comment: Where do you assign to `self.myPeripheral`?

Comment: I do that in `didDiscoverPeripheral`. See edit #2.

Comment: What is your peripheral?  Can the LightBlue app from the app store discover its services?

Comment: It's a Tile device. Yes, the LightBlue app can discover its services. There are quite a few of them (10 actually).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99100/discussion-between-paulw11-and-randall).

Comment: @Alex did you ever figure this out??